# 'Questions' object has no attribute 'strip'

Tags: python, django, audio, django-views

I am trying to give the post an audio by gTTS method. 
while doing this audio work on this post, i am getting the error 'Questions' object has no attribute 'strip'.

```
def qpage(request):
    contact_list = Questions.objects.all()
    paginator = Paginator(contact_list, 1) # Show 25 contacts per page
    page = request.GET.get('Q')
    contacts = paginator.get_page(page)
    spk = Questions.objects.get(id=page)

    tts = gTTS(text=spk, lang='en')
    tts.save("pcvoice.mp3")
    os.system("start pcvoice.mp3")
    return render(request, 'data/quit.html', {'contacts': contacts})
```

Comment: Please provide the full traceback...

Comment: `gTTS` requires a string for the `text` argument, but you are passing a `Questions` object - hence the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error occurs since you `spk` is a **`Questions` object** (you better rename the object to `Question`). This is not a text object.

In order to convert the question text to speech, you need to fetch the *question text* from it. For example:

```
def qpage(request):
    contact_list = Questions.objects.all()
    paginator = Paginator(contact_list, 1) # Show 25 contacts per page
    page = request.GET.get('Q')
    contacts = paginator.get_page(page)
    spk = Questions.objects.get(id=page)

    tts = gTTS(text=spk.question_text, lang='en')
    tts.save("pcvoice.mp3")
    os.system("start pcvoice.mp3")
    return render(request, 'data/quit.html', {'contacts': contacts})
```

(or the name of the *field* that stores the text of the question).

Note that you will need to find a way to pass the file stream to the client. You can do that by creating a dedicated view that obtains the mp3 as a stream and then wraps it into a response.

Comment: Isn't `question.text` instead `question_text`?

Comment: @MauroBaraldi: well like said, we do not know the name of that attribute. I used the models defined in the Django tutorial, where it is `question_text`: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/intro/tutorial01/#creating-models